# unable to set the size of image using UIL

Tags: android, listview, universal-image-loader, custom-lists, horizontallist

[image]

I have two custom listviews, one is vertical and other is horizontal. And horizontal is inside vertical list. Part of vertical list is below

```
    <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/hlistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:background="#fff"
    />
```

I've used this library to handle horizontal list view. Row template for horizontal list view is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:padding="6dip"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="likes"
/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/IVImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/stalker"
/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When i populate data in horizontal list inside My array adapter using UIL library it shows me small images and image width changes according to the size of textview. Mean when i write long text in textview it shows me image width equal to the width of textview.

This is my custom adapter for my horizontal listview.

```
public class HomeHoriLVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HomeSliderClassForAdapter> {

Context context;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
DisplayImageOptions options;

public HomeHoriLVAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<HomeSliderClassForAdapter> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(context, "MyFolderCache");

    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
     // Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                  // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
                 .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
                 .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())                    
                 .build();
     // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
     imageLoader.init(config);
        //imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(a));
       // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.stalker_logo_imageload)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
        .build();

//          https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-    Loader/blob/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/DisplayImageOptions.java
//          link for more functions of DisplayImageOptions();
    this.context = context;

}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtDescription;
    ImageView IVImage;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    HomeSliderClassForAdapter rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_listitem, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        holder.IVImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IVImage);
        holder.IVImage.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        holder.IVImage.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    Session asd = new Session(getContext());
    asd.getAccessToken();


    holder.txtDescription.setText(rowItem.Description);
    display(holder.IVImage, rowItem.PhotoURL.concat("?access_token=" + asd.getAccessToken()));




    return convertView;

}





public void display(ImageView img, String url, final ProgressBar spinner)
{
    img.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    img.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }

});
}

public void display(ImageView img, String url)
{
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

            }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }

});
}



}
```

I want my image width to match parent, mean equals to my screen width and height equals to the height of horizontal list view which in my case is 155dp.

Comment: UIL always keeps aspect ratio. Maybe you should use `android:scaleType="centerCrop".`

Comment: even after setting centreCorp it is not showing full image. i dont think it is due to UIL.I want my each item's width of horizontal listview to equal to width of my horizontal list view

Comment: i have also added image now

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
LayoutParams param=(LayoutParams) holder.IVImage.getLayoutParams();
        param.width=image_dim;
        param.height=image_dim;
holder.Places_iv.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Comment: I want my each item's width of horizontal listview to equal to width of my horizontal list view

Comment: you meen that you want the item itself to be equal to width of horizontal list view  to do  use the above but instead of setting width and height for image view set it on layout that containing the imageview and textview